# How to set up location auto completion in Swift UI textfield?

Tags: swiftui, autocomplete, location, textfield

is it possible to get location suggestions aka autocompletions in textfield in Swift UI? For example I type „Par“ in Textfield and the app shows automatically a few suggestions like in the picture below. Is there a short and smart way to do it. I haven’t found anything for Swift UI yet.
Many thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8zfd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. Search for SearchBar in SO there are several questions on it

Comment: @cedricbahirwe thanks. But there is no location suggestions neither…

Comment: I think you need to look into some third parties API or SDK, such as `Places SDK` from Google

Comment: Related link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959575/what-is-a-good-unlimited-alternative-to-google-places-api

Comment: If do you want to implement the AutoSuggestion feature, you can refer to this - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-filter-your-data

& for the data, you will have to fetch an array from API.

Comment: @Sengard had you find exact solution for this?